# OCaml - a function which returns all the prefixes of a list

Tags: ocaml

For `[1;2;3]`   , I want to return `[[]; [1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]]` . I have hit a wall and i need help, this is what i have done so far

```
let rev list =
  let rec aux acc = function
    | [] -> acc
    | h::t -> aux (h::acc) t in
  aux [] list

let prefixes xs = 
  let xs = rev xs in
  let rec xs = function
    | [] -> [[]]
    | hd::tl -> xs::tl in
  xs
```

Please help me, I know that probably most of what i have done so far is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution I found. Although it's probably not the best since I need to reverse the list at the end.

```
let prefix l = List.rev (List.fold_left (fun acc itt -> ((List.hd acc)@[itt])::acc) [[]] l);;
```

Comment: Can you walk me threw what you did cause i am really new to OCaml

Comment: @Thanospan I'm going to assume your familiar with fold. If not visit [this](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2011sp/recitations/rec05.htm). So inside List.fold_left itt will be an element of l. Example the first time it will be 1 then 2 then 3 ... acc is what you currently have and it starts with [[]] an empty int list list. So lets say we are at itt = 1 then the head of acc is going to be []. We concat that head to itt = 1 to make [1]. acc will be saved as [[1];[]] We make that the new head of acc. So when fold_left iterates again to make itt= 2 the head of acc will be [1]. **next**

Comment: Again we take the head = [1] and concat it to [2]. So we have [1;2] and we save the new acc as the the [[1;2];[1];[]]. So you might see the basic idea. When itt = l[n] where l[n] is the nth position of the list l. We want the head of acc to be the list with elements l[0];l[1];..;l[n-1] (containing all the elements up to but not including l[n]).  Then we combine the two to make our desired list contain all the elements l[0] to l[n]. Then basically add that to the top of acc. In the end the list is actually reversed so I call List.rev to reverse it. Feel free to ask if you're confused.

Comment: Ok i understood thanks and by the way can i ask you if u know a way to reverse the order of lists which are inside list? For example [[];[1];[2;1];[3;2;1]] into [[];[1];[1;2];[1;2;3]] without using already implemented commands like List.rev or List.fold_left...  @syed

Answer (score 3):

The usual question to ask is how you could get the prefixes of a list given a function that returns all the prefixes of a shorter list.

Say your list is `[1; 2; 3]`. The shorter list would be `[2; 3]`. All the prefixes of this shorter list are `[]`, `[2]`, and `[2;3]`. How could you get your desired list of prefixes from this list? It seems pretty straightfoward: you just need to add `1` to the front of all of them. Plus you need to add a new empty prefix.

As a base case, the list of all prefixes of [] is just [].

This seems like a workable way to solve the problem, except that the best way to do it is using a function from the `List` module. Since this looks like homework, I'm not sure that's allowed.

I hope this helps.

As a side comment, your `rev` function looks good to me. But you might not need it to solve the problem. Maybe you could write your own `map` function instead.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems much simpler than solution posted before. Beware that `List.map` aren't tail-recurssive.

```
let rec prefixes l = match l with
    [] -> []
  | x::xs -> [x] :: List.map (fun a -> x :: a) (prefixes xs);;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let rec prefixes  = function
       []   -> [[]]
  | x::tl   -> []::List.map (fun li -> x :: li) (prefixes tl);;
```

Test :

```
# prefixes [1];;
- : int list list = [[]; [1]]
# prefixes [1;2];;
- : int list list = [[]; [1]; [1; 2]]
# prefixes [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[]; [1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine we have a left fold:

```
# List.fold_left (Fun.flip List.cons) [] [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [3; 2; 1]
```

It's then easy to reverse that and get ou original list back.

```
# List.rev @@ List.fold_left (Fun.flip List.cons) [] [1;2;3];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

That seems useless, but let's change that function just a little bit.

```
# let f i x = 
    let i' = x :: i in
    print_endline 
    @@ String.concat ";" 
    @@ List.map string_of_int 
    @@ List.rev i'; 
    i'
  in
  List.rev @@ List.fold_left f [] [1;2;3];;
1
1;2
1;2;3
- : int list = [1; 2; 3]
```

Oh, at each stage of the fold we have a prefix of the list. We just need to capture those. Let's write a new function.

```
# let rec scanl f i lst =
    match lst with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> 
      let i' = f i x in 
      i' :: scanl f i' xs;;
val scanl : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a list = <fun>
# scanl (Fun.flip List.cons) [] [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[1]; [2; 1]; [3; 2; 1]]
# List.map List.rev 
  @@ scanl (Fun.flip List.cons) [] [1;2;3];;
- : int list list = [[1]; [1; 2]; [1; 2; 3]]
```

But `scanl` isn't tail-recursive, so with the help of OCaml 4.14's [`tail_mod_cons`](https://v2.ocaml.org/manual/tail_mod_cons.html), we can make it tail-recursive.

```
# let[@tail_mod_cons] rec scanl f i = function
    | [] -> []
    | [x] -> [f i x]
    | x::y::xs -> 
      let i' = f i x in 
      let i'' = f i' y in
      i' :: i'' :: scanl f i'' xs;;
val scanl : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a list = <fun>
```